# Help me decide on web app architecture

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a little unique requirements for web development.

I've been tasked with develop new web application for be a front-end UI for my company's products back-end. Unfortunately, I have 2 back-ends, one in .NET with MSSQL, another in PHP with MySQL (both are workflow engines, so I guess not much interaction going on). But not both at the same time.

So my focus requirements are.

1. Performances. It must be fast, so say goodbye to good ol' ASP.Net webform.
2. Interoperability. I mean, I can easily reuse existing codes as much as I can when I have to switch between the 2 back-ends.
3. A little eye-candies. I guessed jQuery should be enough. Nothing to worry here maybe?

I'm looking at ASP.NET MVC right now. Or something like [this](http://www.search-this.com/2010/04/26/asp-net-linq-jquery-json-ajax-oh-my/).

Thank you very much. :D

Comment: The front-end should have nothing to do with the back-end, so point #3 is irrelevant.

Comment: Agreed. But I noted it just in case someone might suggests something like Silverlight. Thank you for your respond

Comment: jquery and silverlight have nothing to do with your server.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you id go with MVC, this way you can seperate your views and incorporate JQuery really easily.

in regards to your backend requirements, id create 2 Entity framework context's one pointing to MySQL and the other to SQL server.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to use ASP.NET MVC. :D